# Flutter hot reload not refresh current browser window until I focus it

Tags: flutter, browser, emulation, reload

I am writing a test application in Android Studio. Hot reload works fine in the Android emulator (Google Pixel), and when saving the project, the application immediately overloads in the emulator window.

But if you **open the application in a browser emulator**: Chrome or Edge, the application is NOT updated in it **until I move the mouse cursor to the browser area**. This is very annoying, maybe there is a way to overcome it?

[Picture from console when doing "Hot Reload"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQOAl.jpg)

The picture shows an example of **the application waiting for 7 seconds** while I move the mouse to the browser window.

It is enough to move mouse there, it is not necessary to click.

Comment: Technically Flutter web doesn't support hot reloading: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041 that's why you're facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter hot reload only applicable for mobile devices and not for web.

Comment: But browser reload the App, when I Just hover browser window. Is it normal behavior?

Comment: @DmitryZ, As per the FAQ of Flutter web hot reload is not supported yet.

Comment: Thank you! Will wait for this feature )